# global variable become null when listener run

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I try to send calendar date that I get from the activity and send it to fragment  recyclerView via bundle and I received the date correctly but when I press a checkbox and alert the fragment by listener the date value becomes null

this is the Viewholder code

```
    private class addStudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private MaterialCheckBox checkBox;
        private MaterialTextView nameTv;
        private int id;
        private List<StudentAttendeesDataModel> models = new ArrayList<>();

        private addStudentViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.take_attendees);
            nameTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        }

    private void bind(int position) {
        final StudentDataModel dataModel = dataModels.get(position);
        nameTv.setText(dataModel.getName());
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                id = dataModel.getId();
                Toast.makeText(context, "in" + calendarDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (isChecked) {
                    StudentAttendeesDataModel model = new StudentAttendeesDataModel(id, calendarDate, 1);
                    models.add(model);
                    mListener.onCheckedChanged(models);
                } else {
                    StudentAttendeesDataModel model = new StudentAttendeesDataModel(id, calendarDate, 0);
                    models.remove(model);
                    mListener.onCheckedChanged(models);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is code in the fragment.

```
   @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                calendarDate = bundle.getString(DATE_CALENDAR_KEY);
            }
        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student_recyclerview, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        dataSource = new DataSource(getActivity());
        List<StudentDataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
        List<StudentAttendeesDataModel> data = dataSource.getStudentAttendenas();
        adapter = new AttendeesAdapter(2, data, getContext(), this);
        adapter.setOnCreateStudentData(dataModels);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        List<StudentDataModel> dataModels = dataSource.getStudent();
        adapter.setStudentData(dataModels);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(List<StudentAttendeesDataModel> models) {
        this.models = models;
    }
```

the value becomes null exactly when I try to put it inside the adapter.

Comment: I use java not kotlin

Comment: You should be collecting it from callback inside onCheckedChanged(...) -> models

Comment: Can you explain more

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by make the variable static ):

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your Attendees adapter to set calendarDate in your adapter and then use that value in your viewholder.

`AttendeesAdapter(2, data, getContext(), this, calendarDate)`

Comment: Put the value as an argument in the constructor or create a variable date in your adapter and a setter method to assign it a value. Call the setter method from your activity to set the value.